# Show that $T$ is Linear

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T:P_3→P_2$ be the mapping defined by $T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3)=5a_0+a_3x^2$

a. Show that $T$ is linear

b. Find a basis for the kernel of $T$

c. Find the basis for the range of $T$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What were your attempts so far?

Comment: Please say what you have tried. Just uploading a problem is not the right way.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 0):

You just have to look up the definitions of a linear transformation, which is if:

(i) $T(a) + T(b) = T(a+b)$ 
(ii) $T(ca) = cT(a)$

, where c is a constant and a and b are vectors.

So, if you take two polynomials: $p = (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3)$ and $q = (b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3)$ and check if $T$ is *closed under addition and scalar multiplication*, you are done:

$T(p)+T(q)= (5a_0+a_3x^2)+(5b_0+b_3x^2)=5(a_0+b_0)+(a_3+b_3)x^2 = T(p+q)$
$T(cp)= 5ca_0+5ca_3x^2=c(5a_0+a_3x^2)=cT(p)$

As for b) and c), you have to read more in your book what basis, kernel and range means...

Comment: Please do not answer "no effort" questions.

Comment: OK, will not do that from now on. But, I'd say the question asker just has to read the chapter again. But this is perhaps best suited as a comment.